# Need help understanding E/p V/cm.torr

Tags: laser

I am a hobbyist, and lately I've been reading up on N2 TEA lasers.

Here is the article I've been reading so far:
[The TEA Nitrogen Gas Laser](http://technology.niagarac.on.ca/people/mcsele/lasers/LasersTEA.htm)

In the introduction, the author uses the E/p ratio. Which, as he explains, is the ratio of electric field to pressure and discharge length.

In the following excerpt from the site, he derives a gap distance of 0.6mm for the electrodes based on the input voltage and his chosen E/P value. However, I'm having trouble following him here:

> Assuming a value of 200 V/cm-torr (an "accepted" value), an applied voltage of 7500 volts, and a partial-pressure of nitrogen of 608 torr (80% of 760 torr), the electrode spacing would be only 0.6 mm!

Can someone please explain what the E/P ratio is exactly and help me understand how I would exercise this principle myself? I've tried googling it and the results either lead me to more articles that use the E/P ratio without explaining it, or to the price/earnings ratio which is something completely different.

Thank you very much for giving my your very valuable time!

Comment: 200V/cm-torr = 20V/mm-torr = 7500/0.6mm/608=20

Comment: E/P ratio I think is related to the breakdown voltage in Paschen’s Curve.

Comment: This gives me something more to Google. I really didn't know what additional search keywords to use. I'll post back soon as I find more info. I appreciate the comments!

Comment: From what I can see with 200V/torr-cm , it appears to me that it is guaranteed to arc .  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcxHW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torr

[image]

N2 608 torr * 0.06cm gap = 36.5 torr-cm
@ 7500V it seems to be 3x the breakdown voltage, Vb.

I cannot explain what is optimal but at 0.6mm gap, it will trigger an arc, I guess sustained by lasing and current limiting.

Comment: I think my understanding falls apart with the concept of torr-cm. What exactly does this term mean?

Comment: **torr-cm** is the product of **pressure** and **gap** length for a given breakdown voltage.  Thus around 1 atm the curves are positive linear so Breakdown voltage BDV is proportional to either pressure or gap and  product of both.